# Why am i getting "modulenotfounderror : No module named 'flask_pymongo'"

Tags: visual-studio-code, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

With:

```python
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
```

Why am i getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'flask_pymongo'
```

Why am i getting `modulenotfounderror : No module named 'flask_pymongo'`?

I have installed both `flask` and `flask-pymongo` on my system using `pip3` from the `VS Code` terminal.
why am i still getting this error?

I reinstalled both modules multiple times but couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed the code that generates the error, how you installed `Flask-PyMongo`, and how you are running your app, someone may be able to offer some suggestions.

Comment: how you installed ?

Comment: from flask_pymongo import PyMongo . this is the line which is showing error. And i installed Flask-PyMongo from vs code terminal by running the pip3 command. @rickhg12hs

Comment: I'm guessing you are running your code from within VS Code and it is using a different `python`, or within a virtual environment, than the `python`/environment that installs the modules from the VS Code terminal.  Check your `python`s and virtual environments.